# Django redirect doesnt work after posting JSON data

Tags: python, django, redirect

Return redirect doesn't work in an else statement after receiving json data. The same redirect works in an other if statement. In the terminal I can see the GET request for the url I want to redirect to, that is why I found this strange.The print statement works perfectly in else, only redirect fails. My code so far:

**views.py (please let me know if the other views are necessary to answer the question)**

```
def data_type_error_handling(request):
    '''handles all the possible choices after data_type_errors '''
    if '_skip' in request.POST:
        return redirect('data_validation')
    elif 'first_load' in request.session or '_refresh' in request.POST or request.method == 'GET':
        print("data_load vagy refresh")
        error_list = request.session['error_list']
        errors = json.dumps(error_list, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
        if 'first_load' in request.session:
            del request.session['first_load']
        return render(request, "upload/data-type-correction.html",
                                                 {"error_list": errors})
    else:
        raw_data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        data = json.loads(raw_data)
        print(data)
        return redirect('data_validation')

def data_validation(request):
    return render(request, "upload/data-validation.html")
```

return redirect('data_validation') works in the first if statement, but not in else, it stays on the same page where I clicked on the button.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('data-upload', views.data_upload, name='data-upload'),
    path('upload-failed', views.data_upload, name='upload-failed'),
    path('upload-successful', views.data_upload, name='upload-successful'),
    path('data-type-correction', views.data_type_error_handling, name ='data-type-correction'),
    path('data-validation', views.data_validation, name ='data_validation'),
]
```

**data-type-correction.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Data type error correction {% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Data type errors</h1>
    
    <h3 id="data-type-error-h3">There are data type errors in your submission. Please change string characters to numbers in the Amount column.</h3>
    <input type="submit" class="btn-back-correct" id="btn-back-to-upload" value="Back" onclick="history.go(-1)" />
    <div id="main-container">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-submit-correct" id="btn-repost-data-errors" name="_reload">Load corrected data</button>
        <div id="datatype-error-container"></div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <ul id="datatype-action-container">

                {%csrf_token%}
                
                <li><input type="submit" class="btn-submit-correct" id="btn-dismiss-data-errors" value="Skip this data" name="_skip" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you do not need this data?');"></li>
                <li><input type="submit" class="btn-submit-correct" id="btn-refresh-data-errors" value="Refresh error list" name="_refresh"></li>

            </ul>
        </form>
        
        <!--handsontable-->
        <script>
            var errors = {{ error_list|safe }}
            console.log(errors)
            function log (event) {console.log(event)}
                var container = document.getElementById('datatype-error-container');
                var settings = {
                    data: errors,
                    rowHeaders: true,
                    colHeaders: true,
                    filters: true,
                    dropdownMenu: true,
                    contextMenu: true,
                    width: '75.66%',
                    height: 500,
                    minRows: 1,
                    afterChange: log.bind(this, 'afterChange'),
                    afterRemoveRow: log.bind(this, 'removeRow'),
                    afterRemoveCol: log.bind(this, 'removeCol'),
                    afterCreateRow: log.bind(this, 'createRow'),
                    afterCreateCol: log.bind(this, 'createCol'),
                     columns: [
                            {
                        data: 0,
                        type: 'text',
                        width: 210,
                        allowInsertRow: true
                },
                              {
                        data: 1,
                        width: 210,
                        type: 'text',
                },
                            {
                        data: 2,
                        width: 210,
                        type: 'text',
                },
                            {
                        data: 3,
                        width: 210,
                },

                ],
                licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
                colHeaders: [
                'CID',
                'Product',
                'Account',
                'Amount'
                ]

            };
            var hot = new Handsontable(container, settings);

        </script>
        <script src="../../static/app/scripts/fetchData.js"></script>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**data-validation.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Data validation {% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Data validation output goes here</h1>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: doesn't it give any error?

Comment: No, simply nothing happens. In the terminal I can see a POST request because of passing json to the backend, then a GET request with the correct url, but simply nothing happens.

Comment: can you share your ```data_validation``` method?

Comment: it is a simple html page, added to the description.

Comment: I meant the view method ```views.data_validation```

Comment: sorry, my bad, just edited the views.py part. (it is a simple page render)

Comment: Have you ruled out it's a browser issue by trying a different browser? Your code looks all correct. If the get request to the redirect url is being requested, then browser must think it had a redirect, so if page content doesn't change or even addressbar - that sounds really buggy.

Comment: It does the same thing with both FireFox and Chrome. Here are the requests from the terminal:
[15/Jul/2020 14:00:03] "POST /upload/data-type-correction HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/Jul/2020 14:00:03] "GET /upload/data-validation HTTP/1.1" 200 958

Comment: both of the POST and GET requests are after the print statement, can this be the cause of the issue? in my code there is only a redirect after the print.

[['xls_test3', 'p42113', 'R1003', '-'], ['xls_test5', 'p42115', 'R1007', '-']]
[15/Jul/2020 14:04:34] "POST /upload/data-type-correction HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/Jul/2020 14:04:34] "GET /upload/data-validation HTTP/1.1" 200 958